# Find files in one dir that isn't in another dirs

Tags: linux, bash, find

I have written this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR_TORRENTS="/home/simon/.wine/drive_c/users/simon/Datos de programa/uTorrent"
DIR_DESCARGA=/home/simon/torrent-descargas/
DIR_TEMPORAL=/home/simon/torrent-temporal/
cd "$DIR_TORRENTS"
rm -f /tmp/torrent_existentes
for torrent in *.torrent
do
    nombre=`basename "$torrent" .torrent`
    find "$DIR_TEMPORAL" "$DIR_DESCARGA" -maxdepth 2 -name "$nombre" -printf '%f.torrent\n' >> /tmp/torrent_existentes
done
```

With this script I want to get a list of torrent files whose data still exists in the data folders of *uTorrent*.
The script works except when the filename has some characters like '`[]`'. I think the problem is that "`-name`" interprets "`$nombre`" like a pattern. How can I disable this behavior?

---

Well, I've found the solution to this: `nombre=$(basename "$torrent" .torrent | sed 's/\[/\\[/g; s/\]/\\]/g')`

But now I have another problem. I want delete the torrent files whose data doesn't exist in the data folders of *uTorrent*.
I've modified my previous script (*this script doesn't delete nothing because I'm testing first*):

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR_TORRENTS="/home/simon/.wine/drive_c/users/simon/Datos de programa/uTorrent"
DIR_DESCARGA=/home/simon/torrent-descargas/
DIR_TEMPORAL=/home/simon/torrent-temporal/

cd "$DIR_TORRENTS"
for torrent in *.torrent
do
    nombre=$(basename "$torrent" .torrent | sed 's/\[/\\[/g; s/\]/\\]/g')
    if ! find "$DIR_TEMPORAL" "$DIR_DESCARGA" -maxdepth 2 -name "$nombre" &> /dev/null 
    then
        echo "$torrent"
    fi
done
```

But it prints nothing, why?

---

Well, this solved too:

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR_TORRENTS="/home/simon/.wine/drive_c/users/simon/Datos de programa/uTorrent"
DIR_DESCARGA=/home/simon/torrent-descargas/
DIR_TEMPORAL=/home/simon/torrent-temporal/

rm -f /tmp/torrent_existentes
cd "$DIR_TORRENTS"
for torrent in *.torrent
do
    nombre=$(basename "$torrent" .torrent | sed 's/\[/\\[/g; s/\]/\\]/g')
    find "$DIR_TEMPORAL" "$DIR_DESCARGA" -maxdepth 2 -name "$nombre" -printf '%f.torrent\n' >> /tmp/torrent_existentes
done
for torrent in *.torrent
do
    if ! grep -Fq "$torrent" /tmp/torrent_existentes 
    then
        rm "$torrent"
    fi
done
```

But is there any way to write this script more simply?

Comment: try `... -name $(quote "$nombre") ...`

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape nombre:

```
nombre='abc[def]ghi'
printf -v escaped_nombre "%q" "$nombre"
echo $escaped_nombre
```

Comment: Thanks, but this command escape all characters and this provokes that find fails too.

Comment: @Simón - do you know what characters need escaping?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it this way:

```
comm -1 -2 <(cd $DIR_1; find . | sort) <(cd $DIR_2; find . | sort)
```

This will output a list of files common to both directories. You may still need to truncate the "./" prefixed to each line, but that's easily doable when you've got the list of common files.

***Edit:*** If you need files existing only in *either* directory, replace `-1 -2` with:

- `-1 -3` ==> find only files in $DIR_2
- `-2 -3` ==> find only files in $DIR_1

Comment: See the script. The search is in several folders at same time. There is 3 folders and one of the folders has several sub-folders.

Comment: @Simón ahhh... after re-reading the script several times, I finally understand. There *are* 'smarter' ways to do what you want, but your way is easier to understand. Within a few weeks from now, the 'smarter' way may no longer make sense to you. So, I suggest to stick with your solution.